# Intent flags on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I have a widget for my application, which need to be somewhat independent from the app.

The activity workflow should be like this:

Widget -> Activity acting as receiver

Receiver -> LoginPage or Activity A (depending on login status)

LoginPage -> Activity A

Activity A onKeyDown -> Activity B

Activity B onKeyDown -> Home Screen.

I have no problem until Activity B, which sends back to Activity A when I press onKeyDown. I'm using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** flag and finishing the Activity when starting the activity B.

When I move from ActivityA to ActivityB using the CLEAR_TOP flag, I supposed that Activity stack is cleared, then in ActivityB I finish the Activity on the onKeyDown() method, assuming that the App will be closed, but it doesnt. Why?

I'm also trying to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the receiver but I dont understand the mechanism pretty much. Any idea about this?

Comment: When activity A moves to activity B with clear top, the activity stack should be clear. then in Activity B I override the onKeyDown and finish the activity, so i supposed it should close the app but it doesn't, activity A is shown again. I want the app to close on Activity B when pressing onKeyDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, start your activity B if its not started or it came back as the second activity on the BackStack. To finish Activity A, you can call finish() after starting Activity B or add no history flag, when starting A.

Comment: That was the flag I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@JesusS: I doubt if u can finish ur activity in that fashion during a forward transition.

Consider a scenario of moving from `Activity A to Activity B`. Now if u want to kill `Activity A` and want to move to `Activity B` then call the `startActivity(intent);` 
(where ur moving from `activity A to B`) 
without any flags on the intent followed by the `finish()` on `activity A`.

As per my understanding u can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` only during backward transition i.e when u already have that activity on the stack.

Consider the following scenario:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
```

Now if u want to move back from activity D to Activity A by clearing the activities u can go for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

The result is that the Activities D, C, B(LIFO) will be removed from the stack and the `activity A` resumes by calling the **`onResume()`** of Activity A.